# Multiple AS classes in one swf file

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

I'm trying to compile AS files using the mxmlc but the particular class depends on other classes. My command is something like this: mxmlc -includes classA classB -source-path=. com.example.com.classC.

This gave me classC.swf but when I loaded it, it was still looking for classA.swf and classB.swf. Is there anyway I can have just one swf file?

Thanks!

Comment: Normally you'd put shared classes into a SWC; not a SWF.  I think we'd have to see your code.  How are you structuring your project?  How are classA.swf and classB.swf created?  How does classClook for classA and classB?

Comment: It looks for classA and classB swfs via a static URL. It's similar to a plugin architecture where classC is the plugin manager. From a config file, it looks for classA and classB's swfs at a particular URL, and uses the Flex's Loader class. 

I'd like to internalize those swf files somehow. For the code, I'm using this: 
http://github.com/mediafront/osmplayer/tree/master/flash/

The root of the AS files can be found in the "com" dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that classA and classB are `.as` files. In that case, you need not use `-includes` option at all - just import them to your main class (`ClassC`), as you'd normally do and compile using `mxmlc com.example.ClassC` from the folder that contains the `com` folder.

According to [this page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_13.html), `-includes` option is to specify a list of classes to the resulting application SWF file, whether or not those classes are required at compile time. Normally a class in the source path is compiled only if it is required - ie, only if it used by some other class that is being compiler. This option tells compiler to compile a class even if it is not used in any of your classes - may be to use `getDefinitionByName` to create instances of that class at runtime.

Comment: It seemed to work but unfortunately, the way the code works, it's still expecting those other swf files instead of creating them manually. oh well.